# Unity Submodule for Core Code Across Multiple Projects

Tags: c#, git, unity-game-engine, git-submodules

I am working on a few game ideas and proof of concept works that have similar code across each project. I would like to use git submodules (/already am using) and have added to the core code's .gitignore to not track the `*.meta` files in the core's code (so that each project can generate their own .meta files and not use the same .meta files across projects).

Along this thought, is there a way to track in each game the .meta files from the core library?

Here is an example project's structure:

```
Game1/
|-.gitignore (general unity gitignore from https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore)
|-Assets/
  |-Art/
  |-Audio/
  |-...
  |-Scripts/
    |-SomeOtherGame1SpecificScript1.cs
    |-...
    |-Core/ //<- This is the git submodule for the core code
      |-.gitignore // - this .gitignore has the "**/*.meta" line to remove .meta files
    |-...
|-Logs/
|-Packages/
|-UserSettings/
\-Game1.sln // - Unit game .sln project

Game2/
|-.gitignore (https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore)
|-Assets/
  |-...
  |-Scripts/
    |-SomeOtherGame2SpecificScript1.cs
    |-...
    |-Core/ //<- This is the git submodule for the core code
      |-.gitignore // - same core library and source as above (but cloned/update locally)
  |-...
```

Comment: Why not use the same meta files though? And no .. you either ignore them or track them. You can't ignore them in the submodule but then want to track them in the main repository that's not possible using `git` .. the main repository's "authority" ends where the submodule root begins.

Comment: I'm not sure if tracking them between projects will jeopardize the .meta files between projects. I will test this out beforehand and check.

I did find that same conclusion that I cannot track files in the parent project (A) to the submodule (B)

Comment: No it wouldn't .. the meta files store some information like e.g. the default references for a script .. and it makes sure that all references are correctly saved and restored since it also stores the GUID for that script/asset .. something you should never ignore in Unity otherwise you can get into a lot of trouble ;) I have done this before and had like a base application with a lot of even more submodules ;) Just treat it like a normal Unity project/package (you will see that also Unity built-in packages track the meta files as well)

Comment: Thank you @derHugo I appreciate the insight!

Answer (score 0):

After the comment from @derHugo, I've started tracking the .meta files in the current game project I was working on, then set up another quick project and used some of the same scripts without issue.

Seems that tracking those metafiles is okay from submodules across projects!